# Need to apply Primary Indexes and secondary indexes in teradata tables

Tags: teradata

Can some one please help in solving my problem
 I have three tables to be joined ed using indexes in Teradata to improve performance.  Query specified below:-

```
Select b.Id,  b.First_name,  b.Last_name, c. Id,
   c.First_name,  c.Last_name,  c.Result 
from
 (
   select a.Id,  a.First_name,  a. Last_name,  a.Approver1,  a.Approver2
   From table1 a
   Inner join table2 d
   On a.Id =D.Id
   and A.Approver1 =a.Approver1
   And a.Approve2 =D.Approver2
 )  b
Left join
 (
   select * from table3 
   where result is not null 
   and application like 'application1' 
 ) c
On c. Id=b.Id
Group by b.Id,  b.First_name,  b.Last_name, c.Id,
   c.First_name,  c.Last_name, c.Result
```

The above query is taking so much of time since PI not defined correctly. 
 First two tables (table1 and 2) are with same set of columns hence pi can be defined like PI on I'd,  approve1,  approve2
 However,  while joining with table3 am confused and need to understand how to define pi.  Is it something that PI can only work when we have same set of columns in the tables?

Structure of table3 is 
 I'd,  first name,  last name,  result

And table 1 and table2 
 Id , First name,  Last name, Approved 1, Approved 2,  Results

Can you please help in defining primary indexes so that query can be optimised.

Answer (score 1):

Teradata will usually not use Secondary Indexes for joins. The best PI would be `id` for all three tables, of course you need to check if there are not too many rows per value and it's not too skewed.

`GROUP BY` can be simplified to a `DISTINCT`, why do you need it, can you show the Primary Keys of those tables?

Edit based on comment:

PI-based joins are by far the fastest way. But you should be able the get rid of the `DISTINCT`, too, it's always a huge overhead.

Try replacing the 1st join with a `NOT EXISTS`:

```
Select b.Id,  b.First_name,  b.Last_name, c. Id,
   c.First_name,  c.Last_name,  c.Result 
from
 (
   select a.Id,  a.First_name,  a. Last_name,  a.Approver1,  a.Approver2
   From table1 a
   WHERE EXISTS
     ( 
       SELECT *
       FROM table2 d
       WHERE a.Id =D.Id
         and A.Approver1 =a.Approver1
         And a.Approve2 =D.Approver2
     )
 )  b
Left join
 (
   select * from table3 
   where result is not null 
   and application like 'application1' 
 ) c
On c. Id=b.Id
```

Comment: As for now,  primary key is assigned to sno column which was added while creating tables.  However, yeah I can say the data is massive and joining above three tables affects teradata performance....  If i would assign I'd as pi then do you think it would sort the issue? I asked so since the first joining is due to duplicates in the data. Lot of duplicates are there.  And distinct didn't do since not entire row is a duplicate.  There may be another approver for the same id

Comment: @puneetmadan: If you got duplicates you don't have a Primary Key :) I just edited my answer. Btw, what exactly is *massive*?

Comment: Thanks,  I would use the above code..  But I forgot to mention that table 3 is also available with duplicates.  For example :- I'd 1 and application 'app'  and same I'd 1 can have multiple access to an application so I'd 1 will be there in the data more than once however application as well but since the user is having multiple access to an application so there would more than one entry in the data. And application name is there in the table 1 and 2 as well. Please let me know if I should provide you with complete table structures for all tables to be joined.  Thanks in advance

Comment: And as I mentioned there is a primary key but to a irrelevant column sno.  Which is not being used in any of the query.  Therefore the problem exists.

Comment: @puneetmadan: One part of the performance problem might be a huge intermediate spool due to the m-n-joins, did you check QryLogStepsV for spool usage? You can try to do `DISTINCT  First_name,  Last_name,  Result from table3` to remove the duplicates before the join. Table DDL would be nice, but statistics on the number of duplicates is more important.

Comment: iam providing you with tables structure, table 1 and table 2 -                   ID  Name       Application      Approver_1       Approver_2 Result
1 babu       App1                     jay               kumar Done
2 Babu         App1           Kumar                Singh Done and table 3 structure is :-                                                                              id First_name Application Approver           Result
1 babu              App1           kumar           Done
2 Babu              App1            Singh            Done

Comment: @puneetmadan: This is not helpful, better add the CREATE TABLEs to your question and some info about how many rows per `(id/Approver_1/Approver_2)` and per `(id)` exist in avg/max.